# How to change django views into django rest farmework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm creating a shopping cart for my project. I created the cart but I got some help for the writing views for it but they give me Django view instead of django rest framework. I'm creating django rest api . I don't know how to change functions into rest framework in the code there is form but in django rest framework we don't create form. can you help me change the view's functions??? actually my problem is in cart_add function in the views.py

#cart

```
CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'


class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        cart = self.cart.copy()
        for product in products:
            cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in cart.values():
            item['total_price'] = int(item['price']) * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def add(self, product, quantity):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(int(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
def detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart':cart})

@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
    return redirect('cart:detail')

def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:detail')
```

Comment: Can you share what you want your REST API to look like? As a heads up, there's nothing that says you can't use django views to complement your DRF API.

Comment: I want to have a shopping cart . the products that customers want to buy first go to the cart and customers can continuing shopping and choosing products and add or delete some product finally the order would be every thing that is in cart